# Base Class for Angular Component

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

Several of my components have common functionality that I'd like to factor out into a base class.

The components require a service, which I inject in via DI:

```js
export class MyComponentBase {
  constructor (protected myService: MyService) {}

  protected myForm: FormGroup;

  protected doCommonThingWithForm() {}
}

export MyDerivedComponent extends MyComponentBase {
  constructor (protected override myService: MyService) {
    super(myService);
  }

  public NgOnInit(): void {
    this.doCommonThingWithForm();
  }
}
```

It seems weird to me that the constructor of MyDerivedComponent needs to have the service injected as protected, when it in fact is not a base class. But if I inject it any other way I get compiler errors.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Angular 14+ I'd go with the `inject()` function :

That way the injection isn't handled by the constructor and you don't have to worry to pass it to the parent class.

```
export class MyComponentBase {
  private myService = inject(MyService);

  protected myForm: FormGroup;

  protected doCommonThingWithForm() {
     this.myService... 
  }
}

export MyDerivedComponent extends MyComponentBase {
  
  public NgOnInit(): void {
    this.doCommonThingWithForm();
  }
}
```